# Data binding in module

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, android-data-binding

Проект необходимо использовать как библиотеку. Но пока в build.gradle стоит

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

все ок, но как только меняю на 'com.android.library' и пытаюсь перебилдить весь биндинг и DI отваливается. Есть идеи?